# Component Data Flow [VueJS]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, dataflow

**I'm newbie in Vuejs. I have a question about structure data flow**

If we have a component which's used in many other components( 3-4 components).

For example it's `<CreateCard/>` component, so should we put API in own `<CreateCard/>` component and pass props from parent for API or we should put API in parent of `<CreateCard/>` component.

Which is optimize solution? If you guys have any article or tutorials about struturing data flow, construct complex components well, please give me a recommendation

Thank you guys so much for helping me.

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic on SO. If you have a specific problem to solve, please, post the code, as it's unclear what kind of API you talk about. If it's about API calls and fetched data then it belongs to parent component where it can be fetched only once, possibly root component (global Vuex store). If the code works correctly, this may be the question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

well, for me in such a case I will follow "when in doubt, split it out".
splitting the files and dividing the responsibility is always better, I prefer to put all the API calls and vuex tools in a separated directory, and using slots in the reusable components.
here are 2 articles I found for most common tips regarding VueJs best practices
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/10-good-practices-building-maintaining-large-vuejs-projects

https://itnext.io/how-to-structure-my-vue-js-project-e4468db005ac